# Error while using nose

Tags: python, nose, attributeerror, nosetests

Im not able to comprehend why i see this error on only particular machines but not on others.

Im invoking all test cases using nosetest command.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: AttributeError (attribute '__name__' of 'objc_class' objects is not writable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 519, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 564, in _makeTest
    obj = transplant_class(obj, parent.__name__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 644, in transplant_class
    C.__name__ = cls.__name__
AttributeError: attribute '__name__' of 'objc_class' objects is not writable

======================================================================

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: error (C is overriding existing Objective-C class)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 519, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 564, in _makeTest
    obj = transplant_class(obj, parent.__name__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 641, in transplant_class
    class C(cls):
error: C is overriding existing Objective-C class
```

Comment: Different machines or different operating systems?

Comment: Good question, all my machines have same OS(yosemite)

Comment: Is the class name `C` one of yours?   If it is, what happens if you change its name?

Comment: Nope, i don't have any classes of my own with Name C

Comment: are you using PyObjC?

Comment: i do, but i wonder why the behavior is different across machines